# Unbound Block Helper

Tags: ember.js

Is their any Unbound block helper in emberJs. I want to make my whole each block as unbound

something like

```
{{#unbound}}

    {{#each item in view.ItemList}}
        {{do something}}
    {{/each}}
{{/unbound}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is yet no `{{unbound}}` block helper. This feature is currently scheduled for Milestone 1.1. Watch this [issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/444) to stay up to date.

Comment: As a workaround, you could make a custom view class that use a normal Handlebars template (not Ember Handlebars) instead.